# Is it possible to append or setAppends before the get() (or similar) function?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Something like

```php
Model::select('whatever many selects and aliases')
    ->when($somecondition, $q => $q->append('model_attribute')
    ->get()
//  or toSql() or whatever.
```

the thing is the model has a legacy heavy on the db side logic which I'm aiming to extract to php.
I'm ready to make a new column or auxiliary table but wanted to know.

Comment: What is the resulting value of `model_attribute`?

Comment: one of them is a query on other table then some simple sum. 3 - the result

Comment: The problem is when i append to the model (with `protected $appends=['attr']` ) the overhead, although small get significant when i'm querying 1mi rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can just check this solutions this can help.

```
\App\Models\User::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'salary')
    ->when($request['is_salary'], function ($query) {
        $query->addSelect(DB::raw('salary * 1.5 as multiplied_salary'));
    })->get()
```

Comment: So, only using a select itself?
I was hoping to use the setAppends / apends method that I already have a getter/setter in the model.

Comment: maybe something like the inverse of pluck

Comment: That is not possible you can write conditions inside the append attribute

Comment: great idea, i'll make a conditional early return. if you want to make another answer saying its impossible, with that suggestion i'd be glad to mark it as correct